# How to send email from specific address when choosing specific contacts?

Tags: gmail

I use Gmail at home and at work. When I **create** work-related emails, I need to change the **From** field to my work email.

Since I have regular people to whom I send work related emails, I would like an option that when I choose a work related person in the **To** field, the **From** field will automatically change to my work email address.
Does such option exist?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're receiving email to only one address, so that both your work and home contacts use the same address to contact you. If so, you cannot automatically set the `From` field when sending emails.

But if you had two addresses for people contacting you, you could setup default From addresses. When replying to an email, a From address is chosen based on which address was used to receive the message.

Such a scheme means you would need to inform your contacts to use a specific address for work/home related emails. 
You could use, say `eyalev+home@gmail.com` and `eyalev+work@gmail.com` - [anything after the `+` sign is ignored by Gmail](http://www.toolnext.com/2008/04/gmail-how-to-use-plus-sign-for.html).

Then enter your Gmail settings, and go to the `Accounts and import` tab. Under `Send mail as` add  new accounts for `eyalev+home@gmail.com` and `eyalev+work@gmail.com`. Take note of the `Treat as an alias` option to [get the behaviour you want](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1710338&ctx=gmail).

Also see the [official guide to using 'plus' addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?&answer=22370).

Comment: That's aaaaaalmost perfect. I'd like not just replies but new email conversations to also do this detection.

Comment: Now that, I don't think is possible.

Comment: Merf. Well, thanks for detailing what we can do.

Comment: I don't have this problem when replying to emails, only when composing new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here! For years I've been searching for a solution to that.

I agree with @steven-roose, it is not that hard to change the from field.

The problem is: sometimes when I unfortunately **forget to do it**, I end up sending an email from my personal account to a business colleague or a client, by accident. :/

I have 2 email addresses managed from my Gmail inbox:

- my personal one (me@**gmail**.com)
- and my work email (me@**company**.com).

The default "From:" address is my gmail account.

**What is ALREADY good:** When someone writes an email directly to my work email (in "to:" or "CC:" fields), there is an option in Gmail configuration to automatically select the "From:" address. Works flawlessly.

**What is NOT good:** When I write an email to a co-worker, I have every time to **choose manually** my work email in the "From:" field.

**What is ALSO NOT good:** It also happens **when replying to** someone that wrote to the customers service email of my company (**help**@**company**.com), I have also to choose manually my work email.

**What would be a good workaround:**  A solution to set automatically the "From:" field to "me@company.com" if I set specific recipients (anyone@company.com)

*Notes:*

1. I've found this UserScript below (whic could be installed with something like TamperMonkey) that was made to auto-select "from" address when you COMPOSE, but it's no longer available (script is no longer maintained):
   [GMail "Send From" Auto Selector](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/71859)
2. Also, there is [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/PlKmkXv5bIw/35YJZKss83IJ) suggestion in Gmail Help Forum, but no answers to it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is. But I don't think either that changing the from field is that hard, is it? It's a simple select box.